# Error propagation for quadratic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, statistics

I have a very simple question I am struggling with. Lets say I want to propagate the error for some expression $$ y = x^2$$

Lets say I known that $x = 0 \pm 100$. Using standard error propagation I get that $$\sigma_y = 2x\sigma_x$$

This means that the value I get $$y = 0 \pm 0$$

Which I find very counter-intuitive. I know $x$ incredibly imprecisely, yet I know $y$ with perfect precision? What am I missing here? Or is this really the true result?

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is correct, it certainly can't be the true result. It seems to me that you're using a formula that isn't quite adapted to the problem. The "standard" formula for the propagation of error to $y$ is usually derived in the following way:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
y &= x^2 \\ \implies \log{y} &= 2 \log{x}\\
\implies \frac{\Delta y}{y} &= 2 \frac{\Delta x}{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

We arrive at the formula you quote by then multiplying by $y$, and identifying $\Delta y \equiv \sigma_y$ and $\Delta x \equiv \sigma_x$.

Of course, the relative error is not defined when $y=0=x$! Thus, naively using this formula isn't a good idea, since the relative error isn't nicely defined when the "true" value is zero. There is an interesting discussion of this on the [Stats StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/201864) as well as the [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/680555).

Happily, such situations don't arise very often (in introductory labs at least). In an actual experiment I suspect that quick workarounds could be arranged.

---

**EDIT:**

I understand that your question is more related to the "theory" but practically, it seems to me that if you actually had such a situation in a laboratory, it's an indication that you are not using the correct apparatus to measure the quantity in question. The value being zero when the uncertainty is so large is equivalent to trying to measure the mass of a single hair from your head using a kitchen weighing balance.

Answer (score 1):

The method of differentiating to find error works only when the error is much smaller compared to the measured value.
ie: if $x>>\Delta x$.

In general, if $\Delta x$ is the error associated with $x$, then the maximum error associated with $y (=x^2)$ is:
$(x+\Delta x)^2$

$= x^2 + 2x\Delta x + {\Delta x}^2$
So we see the deviation from $x^2$ is $2x\Delta x + (\Delta x) ^2$.

usually error of the instrument would be small compared to measured value and hence ${\Delta x}^2$ can be neglected.
Here that's not the case. Now, we get a large deviation as our intuition says.

Comment: OK this makes a lot of sense, thank you very much. Could you please provide a reference in error in cases when $ \sigma x ~= x $?

Comment: I didn't get your question... but if $\Delta x$ = $x$, it makes your reading $100 \pm 100$. maximum error in $y$ would be : $(\Delta x) ^2 + 2x\Delta x$    $= 3x^2=30,000$. The. minimum error would be $(\Delta x) ^2 - 2x\Delta x$    $= 3x^2 = -10,000$. So $y$ could be between $10,000 + 30,000$ and $10,000 - 10,000$. The range is so because for negative $\Delta x$, $(\Delta x)^2$ would still be positive.

Comment: Could you backup your statement "The method of differentiating to find error works only when the error is much smaller compared to the measured value" with a reference? I strongly doubt that this is true. Also to use the wording "maximum error" seems unfortunately. It suggests an upper bound with 100% certainty. Such a thing does not exists for a distribution which is not bounded.

Comment: @Semoi, hope you realise that 'error' as mentioned in my answer and in the question does not refer to standard deviation, standard error or any mathematical quantity of that kind. Here error in a reading is just the amount of certainty we have. In a normal distribution it may be infinite with curve never touching the axes and never limiting the values. But in a physical situation, we can have an upper and lower limit for deviation

Comment: If I measure the length of my pencil using a geometry scale, and if the reading obtained is in between 10cm 2mm and 10cm 3mm, I can be sure that it cannot be greater than 10cm 3mm and less than 10cm 2mm. This difference is what we call the error and it could definitely be a closed interval

Comment: As for References, I'm not sure if I know any.. but its common sense that the error in result ($y$) can be calculated as in question and for small errors differentiating the equation would give the error

Comment: Well, I tried to point you in the right direction. Maybe you did not get that. So let me say it in a more direct way: Unfortunately, your initial statement is wrong. Also your last statement is wrong. As a reference you could look up the ISO norm: ISO/IEC Guide 98-3 (2008)

Comment: Sorryy I could not find any contradictions to my statements in that paper. As mentioned above, my statement that errors in measurement can be bounded and that deviations from calculated value cannot always be obtained by differentiating are true to my logic. It would be kind if you could prove me wrong. Let the content review team do the needful

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your error propagation equation. You want to see how an error $\Delta x$ propagates and gives rise to a $\Delta y$. It should be something like $\Delta y = 2 x \Delta x$ which can be rewritten as $ \Delta y / y = 2 \Delta x / x$. So as usual with multiplication you're adding the relative errors in first order.

Comment: It seems we have the same equation and you should get the same result I did

Comment: @user2551700 Did you edit it? Now it looks good but only in first order...

Comment: ...which in this case is obviously not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is a random variable from the normal distribution $N(\mu_x, \sigma_x)$, then $y=x^2$ is a random variable from the (scaled) [$\chi^2_\nu$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) with $\nu=k=1$.
[image]
(copied from wiki)

The image shows the $\chi^2_\nu$ distributions for the scaled variable $\chi =Z^2$, where $Z = (x - \mu_x)/\sigma_x$ is $N(0,1)$ distributed. Hence, the image shows that even if $\mu_x = 0$ the mean of $y$ is non-zero,  as you expected. Doing the calculation one can show that the [expectation value of $\chi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) is given by $E[\chi] = E[Z^2] = \nu$. Since one can always scale the variable $x\to Z$ such that the mean value becomes zero, we will consider this special case, but keep $\sigma_z$ explicitly. Hence, we consider the case $x \sim N(0,\sigma_x)$.

The formal way to tackle your problem is to use the concept of *transforming* the random variable, which leads to the result described above. A "simpler method", which is also directly connected to your question, is to calculate the variance of y,
$$
\sigma^2_y = %Var[y] = 
\left(
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}
\right)^2 \sigma^2_z
= (2Z)^2 \sigma^2_z
$$
which is mainly the formula you already had. However, in "my" relation the random variable $Z$ does not appear linear, but squared. Taking the expectation value of this expression, we obtain
$$
\sigma^2_y = (2 \sigma_z)^2 \, E[Z^2] 
=  (2 \sigma_z)^2 \nu = (2\sigma_z)^2
$$
where we used $\nu=1$. Now taking the square root we obtain the result
\begin{align}
 E[y] &= \nu \\
\sigma_y &= 2\sigma_z
\end{align}
or in your notation $y = \nu \pm 2\sigma_z$.

Comment: Further, please note that $E[X^2] \ne E[X]^2$, in general. Hence, we are not allowed to replace the expectation value of $y$ by the square of the expectation value of $x$.

Comment: It'd probably be best to stick to explaining the OP's conceptual question, and avoid providing anything else which would be meant merely to help them solve the underlying homework problem.